# The trait `Responder` is not implemented for `Vec<T>`

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am using `actix_web` in a learning project, and I am facing this error when trying to create a route :

```
the trait `Responder` is not implemented for `Vec<TextAnnotation>`
```

this is the code generating the error :

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

use actix_web::{http::StatusCode, web::Json, Result};
use mongodb::{
    bson::{doc, oid::ObjectId},
    options::{FindOneAndUpdateOptions, FindOptions, ReturnDocument},
};

use crate::{
    database::mongodb::DB,
    helpers::colors_helpers::{get_next_valid_color, is_color_used, is_valid_color},
    middleware::auth_middleware::UserAuthContext,
    models::text_annotation_model::{
        CreateLabelBody, CreateTextAnnotationBody, CreateTokenBody, Label, TextAnnotation,
        UpdateLabelBody,
    },
    object::{common::Message, error::ApiError},
};

// ...

#[get("/")]
async fn get_annotations(
       // ^ the trait `Responder` is not implemented for `Vec<TextAnnotation>`
    page: web::Query<i64>,
    count: web::Query<i64>,
    req: HttpRequest,
) -> Result<Vec<TextAnnotation>, ApiError> {
    let auth = get_auth_ctx(&req);

    let res = AnnotationController::get_page(page.0, count.0, auth);

    if res.is_err() {
        return Err(res.err().unwrap());
    }

    Ok(res.unwrap())
}
```

`TextAnnotation` and its inner fields already implements the Responder traits.

```rust
use actix_web::{
    get, post,
    web::{self},
    HttpRequest, Result, Scope,
};

use crate::{
    controllers::annotation_controller::AnnotationController,
    helpers::request_helpers::get_auth_ctx,
    models::text_annotation_model::{CreateTextAnnotationBody, TextAnnotation},
    object::error::ApiError,
};

// ...

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct TextAnnotation {
    #[serde(rename = "_id", skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub id: Option<ObjectId>,
    pub content: String,
    pub user_id: ObjectId,
    pub tokens: Vec<Token>,
    pub labels: Vec<Label>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Token {
    #[serde(rename = "_id", skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub id: Option<ObjectId>,
    pub start: i64,
    pub end: i64,
    /// reference a label in the labels array
    pub label: ObjectId,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Label {
    #[serde(rename = "_id", skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub id: Option<ObjectId>,
    pub name: String,
    pub color: String,
}

impl Responder for TextAnnotation {
    type Body = BoxBody;

    fn respond_to(self, _req: &actix_web::HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse<Self::Body> {
        HttpResponse::Ok().json(self)
    }
}

impl Responder for Label {
    type Body = BoxBody;

    fn respond_to(self, _req: &actix_web::HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse<Self::Body> {
        HttpResponse::Ok().json(self)
    }
}

impl Responder for Token {
    type Body = BoxBody;

    fn respond_to(self, _req: &actix_web::HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse<Self::Body> {
        HttpResponse::Ok().json(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: The [`Responder`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/trait.Responder.html) documentation pretty clearly shows that  `Vec<T>` does not implement `Responder` for any `T`. Perhaps you meant to return `Json<Vec<TextAnnotation>>`?

Comment: I'd also suggest replacing the `if res.is_err()` hack. It seems the types are all compatible, so it's not clear to me why you don't just return `res`. If you need to wrap the `Vec` in `Json` as per my above comment, you can do `res.map(Json)`. It just seems weird to me that you test `res.is_err()` but in both the `Err` and `Ok` cases you just put the result back together as it was, so it's all just a no-op.

Comment: @cdhowie yes you are right, a lot of context switching (between languages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `@cdhowie`:

All I needed was to import `Json` from `actix_web::web` and return the value as `Json<Vec<T>>` and that's it.